# Equivalent pointer probe from MSVC to GCC in a library

Tags: c++, gcc, signal-handling, seh, memory-access

First, let me say I'm primarily a Windows developer.

I'm looking at porting some existing code C++ code from Windows+MSVC to Ubuntu+GCC.  Part of what I'm porting includes an MSFT-only idiom that I'm not sure how (or if) one can support on GCC.  Here is MSVC pseudo-code, simplified and ignoring things like a compiler complaining about initialized-but-not-used variables, or optimizers removing irrelevant code:

```
bool ProbeIntPointer( int * p )
{
    bool fValid = TRUE;

    __try {
      int x = *p;
    }
    __except( ExecuteHandlerForMemoryAccessFailure() )
    {
        fValid = FALSE;
    }

    return fValid;
}
```

This works via structured exception handling, an MSVC extension.  The deref of *p might fail, but if it does, it generates an exception that is caught and handled by the __except block.

The code being ported is going to be a library, either a static library or a shared object, not sure what's required yet.  Therefore, I'm guessing that installing my own signal handler for segfault/bus-error is not really allowed; I think I have to leave that alone for the program that's using my library to control.

Is there any way to do this under these constraints?

Comment: Personally I would question the need for such a function to begin with. If there needs to be a function like this, then it's an indicator of worse problems in the code, problems that are simply silenced and not really fixed properly. Not to mention that it could give false results, as the pointer might be invalid (i.e. not initialized, out of bounds, etc.) but still appear to be pointing to memory mapped to the process which wouldn't trigger the exception.

Comment: I am not aware of any way to do this on linux except via segfault signal handler or something very intrusive like having another process ptrace the faulting process. A library should not do either of these things.

Comment: Fail fast, that's my motto.

Comment: There is also [userfaultd](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/userfaultfd.2.html) if the kernel is compiled with it enabled (I haven't checked Ubuntu). I haven't used it before, but I expect it to be ill-adviced for a library for the same reasons that registering a signal handler is.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I use this trick to catch (WIN32) exceptions generated by aberrant ASIO drivers.  I'd rather do that than have them bring the program down.

Comment: Linux has no equivalent to Windows' (very nice) SEH mechanism, sadly.  It's more of an operating system feature than a compiler extension, although some compiler support is obviously required.

Comment: I think [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060927-07/?p=29563) is also relevant to your topic.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yeah, similar to what Paul Sanders said.  My library is intended to be used in a data center setting, and will be used by many other services.  If the other services pass me a bad pointer, and there is a crash in my code, it'll be MY pager going off at 2AM for me to do initial diagnostics.  I'd much rather return an error to the aberrant service and let THEM be paged.

Comment: @heapunderrunj very interesting link.  My actual situation is more complicated than the simplified version I presented, so I'm not sure what Raymond has to say applies, but he's a really, really smart guy; I'm very familiar with him and his work. I don't know him personally, but I have some friends who do.  I'll ask him directly.
The actual probe can't really be done in GCC/Linux so I'll have to work around it, but it's a good enough point in general that I'll bring the issue up with the guys who own the Windows version

Comment: @TimWilliams That link isn't really relevant.  SEH is much more robust than that, and, on Windows, is the method of choice to catch a bad access.

Comment: The one- time only guard exception looks problematic. In the existing code, this exception would be unilaterally caught, and we'd return an error from our library,  but we would have swallowed an exception someone else wanted. And as a DLL, I can never tell what the main exe is doing. In addition, I just discovered another layer of exception handling at our API level, and now I'm doubly worried.  The code is really pretty old and stable,  though, so I'm probably worrying for no reason. Well,  except for the whole linux port problem

Answer (score 0):

> The code being ported is going to be a library, either a static library or a shared object,

Here's where the buck stops. While other platforms also have handling of segmentation faults, a library can *never* assume it has the right to install the handler for that. That might (and will) clash with what the application wants to do!

So, nope, this is by design not portable.

Also, if your code needs this, you need to sanitize your code statically, I'd say: you should never end up in a situation where you're not *sure* whether a pointer is (still? already?) valid!

Comment: The fundamental layout of the code is inviolate. That's what the existing code does, that's what I have to try to make it still do. I've never understood why the most common answer on stack overflow is "don't do it that way". That's not an option. The only answers that make sense are "this is how" or "you can't do that".  And, this is a library.  The pointer is a user-supplied parameter.  Of course I'm not sure that the pointer is (still? already?) valid.  No library ever is.  My library is used in a place, though, where if it crashes in my code, I get paged.  If I return an error, I don't.

Comment: I fully get that. And as you notice, my answer is "can't do that (and you really shouldn't)", because that's what a nice person answers when asked how to teach angry Kodiak bears how to do pottery! That's not because I think I'm smarter than you or anything, it's just that what I see worries me, because it's indicative of being in a dangerous situation that should altogether be avoided. (Also, we both agree there's something wrong with the program, and it's unfair you get to be the one to handle it, not the caller)

Comment: Now that's really not very comparable to what your code does on windows, and just like the original, this can't detect pointers to data that is uninitialized or already freed, but still on a mapped page, but: if you are willing to restrict yourself to one operating system you're porting to, say Linux, and performance is of secondary interest: /proc/self contains a pseudofile listing all the *mappings* into your process's memory space. If you get a pointer into a region in there, it's going to not be accessible. I don't think there's a syscall to check that, so you'd need to parse that file...

Comment: ...yourself for every pointer, as the mappings could change at any time.

Comment: The closest to a syscall that could be used for that is possibly `madvise`. Set an attribute of the page your pointer is in and carefully check the error. But using it, for example to tell the kernel you'll need some page soon, has real side effects, so I'd use it very consciously!

Comment: Thanks that's very interesting. Probably not going to be what I do for production, but cool to learn. And sorry if I came across as an angry bear. Not my intention at all; tone gets lost sometimes when typing.

Comment: You did not come across as angry bear. A program relying on a library to tell it it uses invalid pointers is an angry bear